# Как изменить title кнопки "back" в navigationItemBar Objective-C (Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Нужно изменить title кнопки "back" на "Назад" в следующем контроллере. Использую следующее в prepareForSegue перед вызовом контроллера через segue:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showSaveProductDifficultTVC"]) {

UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Назад", returnbuttontitle) style:     UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton; 
}
```

В итоге вместо "Назад" у меня показывает "back". Так происходит только со словом  "Назад" или другими русскими словами, если использовать какое нибудь бессмыслицу, например @"ььь", то все отлично.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема.

Дополнение:

Проблема в моем случае заключалась в том, что тестирование приложения производил на iPhone 4S, где в navigationItemBar не входили по размеру кнопки "Назад", "Сохранить"  и  title. И если сократить title или название кнопок navigationItemBar, или развернуть устройство, то все нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если уменьшить немного шрифт.

Comment: Просто это похоже больше на баг, так как логичнее было бы title отобразиться не полностью, например так: сложный про... Ведь именно так и происходит при создании кнопки назад в коде или storyboard.

Comment: Возможно и баг.

Answer (score 2):

Вам не обязательно создавать программно кнопку "назад" с разной локализацией. Система же это делает сама.

Только в Вашем случае необходимо изменить базовую интернационализацию.

По умолчанию у Вас в info.plist установлено:

**Localization native development region = en**

Из за этого вместо "Назад" показывает "Back". Поменяйте на **ru** и будет "Назад"

Вы можете добавить в проект поддержку языков и убрать галочку "Use Base Internatialization". Текст кнопки будет меняться в зависимости от языка устройства.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таком случае если title будет длинным, то текста "Назад/Back" не будет.

p.s. Кнопке можно так же легко задать цвет/шрифт/размер и изменить индикатор.

Answer (score 1):

Переместите код изменения `title` в метод `viewDidLoad` нужного Вам контроллера

Обновление:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Назад" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(onBackButtonTapped:)];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=newBackButton;
    }

    -(void) onBackButtonTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
           [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Да это изменяет title кнопки, но с изменением строки 
         self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton; на     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton; А главное кнопка не делает переход назад.

Comment: Кроме того этот код в segue работает нормально в других контроллерах в том же приложении.

Comment: Когда вы меняете на `leftBarButtonItem` Вам также необходимо указать селектор для новой кнопки. Пример кода в ответе!

Answer (score 0):

Изменить шрифт в navigation bar можно следующим образом:

```
NSDictionary *size = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:17.0],NSFontAttributeName, nil];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = size;
```

Далее, при изменении ориентации можно возвращать его обратно, так же можно изменять шрифт только если title кнопки возврата соответствует "Назад".

К слову, можно задать в storyboard текст кнопки возврата у RootViewController в Navigation Item один раз, и он распространится на весь Navigation Controller:
[image: Title back button]

Answer (score -1):

Надежней сделать свою кнопку "Назад" и поставить ее как `.leftBarButtonItem`.
Кнопку back делает система, поэтому она в любой момент может измениться. С твоей кнопкой такого уже не произойдет.

UIBarButtonItem* backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self 
                                                                  action:@selector(barButtonBackPressed:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?